# Accessing Embedded ActiveMQ Artemis with Hawtio

Tags: activemq-artemis, hawtio

I have Spring Boot application that includes an embedded ActiveMQ Artemis and Camel. This uses the following ActiveMQ dependency:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
        <artifactId>artemis-server</artifactId>
        <version>2.18.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

I also use Jolokia as dependency. When connecting to the application with a remote Hawtio instance the Camel plugin is enabled and I can also see Camel and ActiveMQ Artemis through the JMX Plugin. However the ActiveMQ plugin is not enabled (though it is included in a default Hawtio installation).

How can I make Hawtio recognize ActiveMQ, so that it enables the Hawtio ActiveMQ Plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ActiveMQ plugin shipped with Hawtio is for the ActiveMQ "Classic" broker, not ActiveMQ Artemis. Therefore, it won't detect the embedded instance of ActiveMQ Artemis.

ActiveMQ Artemis itself has a [Hawtio plugin](https://github.com/apache/activemq-artemis/tree/main/artemis-hawtio) consisting of three parts:

1. [artemis-console](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/activemq/artemis-console/2.18.0/) (rename as `console.war`)
2. [artemis-plugin](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/activemq/artemis-plugin/2.18.0/) (rename as `artemis-plugin.war`)
3. [activemq-branding](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/activemq/activemq-branding/2.18.0/) (rename as `activemq-branding.war`)

You could download those war files and deploy them in your web application server (assuming you have one). I've done this on Wildfly 24 and it worked fine once I relaxed security on the remote ActiveMQ Artemis instance (allowing "guest" users and disabling CORS in `jolokia-access.xml`). Of course, in production you'll want to sort out the security issues, but this should get you moving in the right direction.

Comment: Thnx, this wasn't clear from the Hawtio documentation (https://hawt.io/docs/plugins/ and http://hawtio.github.io/hawtio/plugins/activemq/). I tested this with classic and indeed the plugin now shows. But there is also a Artemis Console (for example used with EAP) and which is also noted in the Artemis documentation "JMX and the Web Console" (https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/management.html). Is it possible to use the Artemis web console from my Remote Hawtio instance?

Comment: The web console used with JBoss EAP is not based on Hawtio and is specific to EAP so it won't help you. I updated my answer to deal with the other part of your comment.

Comment: I think the artemis-console.war already contains Hawtio. I was able to deploy it successfully on Wildfly (together with artemis-plugin.war and activemq-branding.war). I could also connect to my application (Spring Boot with Jolokia/Artemis) and can see "org.apache.activemq.artemis" as JMX , but somehow not 'the right' mbeans are exported so that the Artemis Console plugin really is triggered. I have set explicitly <jmx-management-enabled>true</jmx-management-enabled> in the broker.xml. Seems that some other things are also needed.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the advice of Justin Bertram I did the following:

1. Download [Wildfly](https://www.wildfly.org/downloads/)
2. Download [ActiveMQ Artemis](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/download/)
3. Unzip them both and copy the web directory of Artemis (i.e. /apache-artemis-2.18.0/web) to the deployments directory of Wildfly (i.e /wildfly-24.0.1.Final/standalone/deployments)
4. Start Wildfly and connect to the Jolokia endpoint of the remote ActiveMQ Artemis Broker.

Comment: Isn't this the same basic procedure I outlined in my answer? The `web` directory in the ActiveMQ Artemis distribution contains the same 3 resources you need which I linked to in my answer.

Comment: Yes, the procedure is the same, but just the three files weren't enough. The complete content of the web directory is needed to get the Artemis tab and user interface.

Comment: The three files are, in fact, sufficient. None of the other content from the `web` directory is directly related to the operation of the console. I updated my answer to clarify the situation.

Comment: Yes, the three files are sufficient. The only thing is that I really needed to use them from Artemis version. The files I downloaded directly didn't give me the Artemis tab in Hawtio somehow.

Comment: I was able to get it working with the files from Maven as outlined in my answer so you definitely don't need the files from the ActiveMQ Artemis distribution. I'm not sure what you were doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The [Artemis Console](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.activemq/artemis-console) is, as already pointed out in this thread, powered by Hawtio. [ActiveMQ Branding](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.activemq/activemq-branding) just adds some logos and [Artemis Plugin](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.activemq/artemis-plugin) provides the "Artemis" tab.

**Regarding authentication**

It is (currently) impossible to use Artemis Console with enabled authentication on newer versions of JBoss EAP/WildFly, since the legacy security subsystem got replaced with Elytron. Artemis Console uses the Artifact [hawtio-war](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.hawt/hawtio-war), which doesn't support Elytron. According to this [Pull Request](https://github.com/hawtio/hawtio/pull/2955), Hawtio only ships with Elytron support on the WildFly specific distribution, [hawtio-wildfly](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.hawt/hawtio-wildfly).

You can, however, omit Artemis Console and ActiveMQ Branding. Just be sure that you provide the same version of Hawtio which the Artemis Console WAR would use. You can find the used Hawtio version for example in the compile dependencies of mvnrepository.com or in the unpacked WAR.

Elytron is currently only supported by hawtio-wildfly 2.17.7 and upcoming versions. This means, you're also limited to the newest version of Artemis Plugin (2.32.0), because this is the only one that supports this Hawtio version (yet).

**TL;DR**

You can deploy Artemis Plugin 2.32.0 together with hawtio-wildfly 2.17.7, and viola, you'll have a "Artemis Console", which supports authenticating by your application users of your EAP/WildFly instance. (Just make sure that you'll enable "management jmx-enabled" for the "messaging-activemq" Subsystem in your standalone.xml)

Further information on configuring Hawtio authentication is found [here](https://hawt.io/docs/security.html)

Comment: NOTE: This is also only supported on Versions before WildFly 27 / EAP 8, because Artemis Console/Hawtio Wildfly do not use the "jakarta.*" namespaces provided by Jakarta EE 9 and later yet...